# How to add mvnrepository.com to artifactory 3.1

Tags: maven, artifactory

How can I mirror http://mvnrepository.com/ as remote repository in my local artifactory (3.1.1.1) maven proxy? I tried both http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ and http://mvnrepository.com/ as URL, but I'm getting a HTTP 404 error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can only mirror or proxy Maven repositories, but as far as I can tell `mvnrepository.com` is *not* a Maven repository, it's just a web index of other repositories.

Comment: I found a post which makes it seem for me that it can be added (http://forums.jfrog.org/Corrupted-jars-from-mvnrepository-td6088932.html), so I asked here: http://forums.jfrog.org/possible-to-add-mvnrepository-com-td7579729.html

Comment: The answer is correct. mvnrepository is not a Maven repository. Look at the download link there - it takes you to repo1. Feel free to add repo1 instead and don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: So, there's not way to use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.prebid/prebid-mobile-sdk as `maven.url` at `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

When you visit the library section it has a link to the "Central Repository Link". Click on it to see the Repository link. For me it was https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ and then adding to the JFrog works